# Hashing password in form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hash, passwords

I would like to know how to hash my password. I have this form for registration:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Uzivatel", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Heslo:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.PasswordFor( x => x.Heslo, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Heslo)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I use mambershipprovider
and there is validation like this

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
   PujcovnaUzivatelDao pud = new PujcovnaUzivatelDao();
   PujcovnaUzivatel uzivatel = 
   pud.GetByLoginAndPassword(username, password); 
   return uzivatel != null;
}
```

simply I just wanna know hot to create hash password during registration a how to validate it during login thank you so much.

Comment: Before you consider implementing secure storage of passwords, please read this article on the Security SE: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/128394

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, especially not if it's security-related. Use ASP.NET Identity for authentication and authorization.

Comment: yes but I use Membership provider... Can anybody tell me, how to add hash method?

Comment: You're missing the point. You **don't** do hashing yourself. You ask your authentication provider, such as Identity or Membership (you should really upgrade that to Identity) to do that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8t4h2es(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes but I dont know how.. the article you sent.. there in not any specific code to do that

Comment: There is, scroll down. :)